# aidl: unable to open file for read

Tags: android, maven, file-io, aidl

I would really appricaiate any help to resolve this issue:
I have an svn trunk project and an svn-bracnch. Both are checked out, and made an different Eclipse works-space from them.

I can build the trunk without any error, it's works perfectly.

When I try to install the branch project I got the following message:

> aidl: unable to open file for read 
>   Can anyone explane what could be the error or why aidl can't open the file in the target folder ?

P.S.: building with maven 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem, re-check out from the repo solved the problem.

Comment: Can you find the file that aidl wants to read in the target folder? I had the problem "Error: android-idl-compiler: unable to open" in IntellijIdea, and I found the reason is that the windows 7 system has limitation for the length of file path. And my aidl file path is too long, so the file couldn't be generated in the target folder. So reducing the length of file path can solve it.